# web based GIS geoprocessing vs desktop based GIS geoprocessing

Tags: geoprocessing, web-gis, desktop-gis

## difference between the WEB and DESKTOP GIS geoprocessing (buffer)

- what is the main difference in the area of processing speed or retrival speed of output
- take in case of contour generation from DEM , what should I prefer in this case desktop or web based gis (in terms of time taken to complete task ,processing speed etc)

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to include the results of your research on this topic so far, please?  That way potential answerers will not simply be re-tracing your steps.

Comment: I am also confused about whether the buffer and contour generation are related, or separate operations.

Comment: separate only ...